# How is the Decimal Class Immutable?

Tags: python, decimal, immutability, metaclass, standard-library

I was playing around with the python3k interpreter and came across the Decimal class in the decimal.py module. Documentation on the class indicates that objects created from the class are immutable. I tried to look into the python library code to see exactly how the programmers coded the class to make it immutable. Unfortunately, I was unable to discover exactly what they had done (mainly due to the fact that the class itself is quite large).

I am curious to know if anyone understands how this class achieves its immutable state. I am thinking it may have something to do with overriding the **getattr**() and **setattr**() methods within the class, but I could not find any evidence of this.

I also noticed that this class is able to hide the attributes it defines in its **slots** variable somehow. Perhaps the class uses some type of metaclass technique to achieve this as well as its immutability.

If anyone has any ideas I would appreciate your feedback. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question. Doesn't seem invincibly immutable to me. Python 2.7.2:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> d = Decimal('1.23')
>>> d
Decimal('1.23')
>>> f = d
>>> f
Decimal('1.23')
>>> d._exp = 1
>>> f
Decimal('1.23E+3')
```

I do see that the documentation says it's immutable. I guess they mean if you use the documented interface, it's immutable. E.g.

```
>>> d += 100
>>> f
Decimal('1.23E+3')
>>> d
Decimal('1330')
```

The way this works is simply that Decimal does *not* define operator overloads for *?*= operators: functions like `__i[op]__`. In that case, `d += 100` translates to `d = d.__add__(100)`, which returns a new object and changes the identity of d while not affecting the original object.

Comment: The example you gave me works as expected on python 2.7.2. Decimal is perfectly mutable by changing its implementation attributes such as _exp. However, if you try to run the same code in python 3.3.2 you will get an AttributeError when you try to access _exp that states the attribute does not exist. I believe the module is written for both python 2 and 3. Perhaps it does not use the same attribute identifiers in the different versions or something

Comment: Yeah, I guessed you were using a different version since some of your statements didn't match up with my observations. Still, the 2.7 documentation claims it is immutable, and yet it isn't quite as immutable as an int.

Comment: In Python 3.3, the decimal module was implemented in C and it is used by default. A pure-Python implementation is still present but not normally used. The C version is significantly faster but some of the implementation details have changed. _exp is an unsupported, use at your own risk method, and is only available in the pure-Python implementation. Its use, or abuse, may lead to unexpected results.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. It never occurred to me that the module may have been reimplemented in C since I found the python version first in the source code. I was pulling my hair out trying to figure out how they did it in python (I thought I was missing some sort of obscure language feature). Thank you and @morningstar very much for helping me